# How to create a uniqueID using UUID with positive values?

Tags: java, uuid

I am trying to code a UUID using .hashCode

At the moment my code generates a uniqueID value but wondering how to stop negative values being generated?

```
int uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().hashCode();
System.out.println (uniqueID);
```

Thanks

Comment: `uniqueID &= 0x7FFFFFFF;`

Comment: Why do you use a `UUID` as a random generator and not something like the `java.util.Random` class?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-unsigned-arithmetic

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println (uniqueID);
```

**Note:**

- `Integer.MAX_VALUE` represents the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer.
- The `&` symbol is a bitwise `AND` operator.
- It works because when we bitwise `&` with `1` it returns the same digit and when we bitwise `&` with `0` it results in `0`.
- Now `Integer.MAX_VALUE` results `2147483647` in decimal value and `01111111111111111111111111111111` in the binary value (32 bit where leftmost bit represents sign i.e. 0 for positive and 1 for negative).
- So when we bitwise `&` a number with this above binary number then we get the same number except that the leftmost bit is now turned into a zero which means we have changed the sign of that number and not it's value.